# Shopify do not have graphql api to finish checkout && payment

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

Create an IOS APP based native react && shopify.It is headless. This app has the ecommerce features, including browse product list, view product detail page, add product to cart, checkout, payment, view own account && orders.

ISO APP use GraphQL Storefront API
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront

I have finish products listing and add to cart by grpahql api.
But now we are trying to enable the checkout feature on the native app, we need to let native app call the Shopify checkout API to proceed the payment and generate the order, however there is no available API to let native app be able to

This solution can not work.
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/checkout-ui-extensions#ui-components
In the IOS APP: can not install sdk successfully

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the **Checkout** object present in the Storefront API, as that is the intended object for your usecase? Since you used it to generate your product listing and add to cart, just continue your development and introduce the Checkout.